# PublishAsync does not fail when MQTTnet server is not running

Tags: c#, mqtt

I am using MQTTNet, a .NET library for MQTT based communication from below link

https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet

I am using `managed MQTT Client` from below link

https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/wiki/ManagedClient

I have below code to `publish` messages to `MQTT server`.

```
 var messagePayload = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
                                      .WithTopic("Topic1")
                                      .WithPayload(message)
                                      .WithExactlyOnceQoS()
                                      .WithRetainFlag()
                                      .Build();

    try
    {
          await mqttClient.PublishAsync(messagePayload);                  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         //Why I am not getting exception? 
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour by design of the MQTT Managed client. It uses an internal queue. All the messages published at added to this queue and are then sent to the server when it is available. 
It also ensures that the messages are not lost and can be resent even if the application restarts. Quote from the project wiki.

> All MQTT application messages are added to an internal queue and processed once the server is available.
>   All MQTT application messages can be stored to support sending them after a restart of the application

Comment: In this case, how do we send message delivery status to the client ? It will be always success!  Do I have to query the end system if message reached or not?

Comment: In this case where successful delivery is guaranteed (Eventual consistency) I'd suggest only returning message acknowledgement to the client. Unless you are worried that the server availability is a frequent and unreliable scenario.

Comment: Another option could be using the ApplicationMessageProcessed event of the ManagedMqttClient class to wait for successful processing to signal the client that the message is processed.

Comment: ApplicationMessageProcessed is not triggering. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266609/applicationmessageprocessed-event-is-not-firing-in-managed-mqttnet-client