# ApplicationMessageProcessed event is not firing in managed MQTTnet client

Tags: c#, mqtt

`MQTTnet` is a high performance .NET library for MQTT based communication.

This is GitHub Link.
https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet . It provides a MQTT client and a MQTT server (broker). The implementation is based on the documentation from http://mqtt.org/.

This is how I have created `managed` MQTT client.
Here is the link
https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/wiki/ManagedClient

```
    // Setup and start a managed MQTT client.
    var options = new ManagedMqttClientOptionsBuilder()
     .WithAutoReconnectDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
     .WithClientOptions(new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
     .WithClientId("Client1")
     .WithTcpServer("broker.hivemq.com")
     .WithTls().Build())
     .Build();


    this.mqttClient = new MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient(new MqttNetLogger("IDMQTTManagedPublisher"));
    await this.mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(new TopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic("RequestTopic").Build());
    SubscribeToApplicationMessageReceived();
    await this.mqttClient.StartAsync(options);
```

Subscription to `ApplicationMessageProcessed` event

```
  private void SubscribeToApplicationMessageProcessed()
  {
    this.mqttClient.ApplicationMessageProcessed += (s, e) =>
    {


    };
  }
```

**Message sending code**

```
      var messagePayload = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
        .WithTopic("RequestTopic")
        .WithPayload(message)
        .WithExactlyOnceQoS()
        .WithRetainFlag()
        .Build();

        await mqttClient.PublishAsync(messagePayload);
```

But `ApplicationMessageProcessed` event is not firing in `managed MQTTnet client`

Comment: updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

This managed client is processing the messages using an internal thread. So you have to wait a couple of milliseconds in order to let the thread process queued items.